Hypothesis testing a property of parameters
Suppose I have $n$ i.i.d observations $X = (X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ generated from some distribution $p(x;\theta)$ where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is an unknown parameter I would like to infer from observations.
I have performed maximum likelihood estimation to obtain MLE estimate $\hat{\theta_{\text{MLE}}} \quad$ using the likelihood function $L(X;\theta)$.
I would like to test a hypothesis that the true parameter $\theta$ satisfies some property i.e. $\theta \in \Omega$. I can only test this computationally i.e. it is not some analytic property. For any $\theta$ I have to simulate some complicated system to check if the property holds.
How can I test the hypothesis $H_1$ that $\theta \in \Omega$ computationally in a frequentist framework?
My first intuitive attempt goes something like this: we know under certain conditions the MLE estimate is asymptotically normally distributed $\hat{\theta_{\text{MLE}}} \sim N(\theta,I_n(\theta)^{-1})$ where $I_n$ is the fisher information matrix. I can estimate this covariance matrix by evaluating the hessian of the likelihood function at $\hat{\theta_{\text{MLE}}}$ and taking its inverse - denote this quantity $H(\hat{\theta_{\text{MLE}}})$.
Now the dodgy part : I then sample say $k$ estimates $\theta^{'}_k \sim N(\hat{\theta_{\text{MLE}}},H(\hat{\theta_{\text{MLE}}}))$, and evaluate whether $ \theta^{'}_k \in \Omega$ using my complicated procedure. I then count the number of successes and this is my confidence to accept my hypothesis, i.e. $\alpha = \sum_{k} \mathbb{1}( \theta^{'}_k \in \Omega) / k$.
Is there any procedure which formalises what I am doing? Is there a better way to approach this problem? I should say that I can't collect any more data.
Cheers
